# How does PHP know which SESSION variable goes with each browser that sets it?

Tags: php, security

I understand that SESSION variables are stored in PHP. 
But, if I close my browser, then go back to the page, how does PHP know that previously set session belongs with my browser?
Ip address?

If it uses an IP, couldn't someone just fake an IP address and login to other users accounts because that is how PHP associates the session with the browser?

Comment: php sets a cookie `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Can't that value be edited to get access to other peoples accounts?

Comment: yes, it's called session-hijacking. that's why you use **HTTPS**

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) (emphasis mine):

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally **sent to the browser via session cookies** and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID.

When a new session is started PHP generates a random string. This ID is then sent back to the browser as a cookie value. Subsequent requests pass this cookie back to the server so it can be looked up and know it's the same user coming back. The random session ID makes it hard for others to guess and gain access to another person's session.

In the most recent version of PHP you can set the [length of the session ID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.sid-length) if you're concerned it's easy to guess.  But statistically the defaults for session ID generation are not a concern for most websites.

The [`session.name`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) configuration determines the cookie name in the browser.  By default it is `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: Can't that value be edited to get access to other peoples accounts?

Comment: @Wyatt you would have to guess the long random id a few billion times before you found a valid one

Comment: Yes.  But one would have to guess the randomly generated string.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443677/is-it-possible-to-pirate-a-session-variable-i-do-not-want-to-know-how